# Compare and go to another view controller

Tags: objective-c, arrays, uiviewcontroller

I have this code:

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    NSDictionary *data = [list1 objectAtIndex:row];
    NSNumber *strt = [data objectForKey:@"ab1"];
    NSNumber *strt2 = [data objectForKey:@"ab1"];
    forlb1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", strt.intValue];
    forlb2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", strt2.intValue];

    NSDictionary *xt = [list1 objectAtIndex:row];
    NSString *name = [xt objectForKey:@"name"];

    NSDictionary *xx = [list1 objectAtIndex:row];
    NSString *name2 = [xx objectForKey:@"name"];

    switch (component)
    {   
        case 0:
            show1 = name;
            label1.text = forlb1;
            break;

        case 1:
            show2 = name2;
            label2.text = forlb2;
            break;
    }
}

- (IBAction)goView:(id)sender 
{    
    if (label1.text < labe2.tex)
    {
        ViewController1 *first = [[ViewController1 alloc]init];
        first.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
        [self presentModalViewController:first animated:YES];
    }
    else
    {
        ViewController3 *third = [[ViewController3 alloc]init];
        third.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
        [self presentModalViewController:third animated:YES];
    }
}
```

My problem is: I can't get ViewController3 if my label1.text < label2.text

When I select from component 1 of Picker view, one of my labels show the Name, and Another, label1 show me a number, same thing happens with component 2 of Picker view, now is ok, but when I should touch the button, I need to go to viewcontroller 1 or viewcontroller 2, depends of: label1.text < label2.text

Help me please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not be comparing `label.text` using the less then `<` operator. Depending on the content of the label, you should either convert the text to number and do a check, or compare strings alphabetically.

This is how to compare strings numerically, assuming that the text represents an integer number:

```
if ([label1.text intValue] < [labe2.text intValue]) {
    ....
}
```

This is how to compare strings alphabetically:

```
if ([label1.text compare:labe2.text] ==  NSOrderedAscending) {
    ....
}
```

Comment: Usually I created a new  2 NSStrings wich is 1 equal to label1.text and another with label2.text, and when i compare these nsstrings, also i have no succes. :( also i created NSNumbers in app delegate, which are equals to my labels, and tried to compare nsnumber, also, nu succes.

Comment: oo.. man.. thank you so much, I this post was very useful, works. thank you so much. Nice..